# How to detect a cycle in a grid in least time complexity possible?

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, cycle

I have a maxiumum 35 character grid it maybe (1x35..5x7) or anything else .The value of each cell on the grid can be binary only.In simulating a game having certain moves which implies a possible  change in the grade state after  a move .If I have to detect the cycle/the period of this game,what algorithm/data structure can I use in the least possible time complexity? I tried a log n tree based approach to store the state of the grid but it wasn't fast enough for my purpose when the period is larger than 2^17.  Is there a technique to perform hashing on the grid state without taking too much memory?

Comment: What form do the state transitions take?

Comment: @Vaughn Cato:Well transitions actually depend on number of true states in the grid

Comment: @VaughnCato:Transformations may increase/decrease number of true states ,almost in a pseudu random manner

Comment: Can you be more specific?  There may be some special structure in the state transitions that can be exploited.  Is there a known starting state?

Comment: @I had an idea ,couldn't I store a single hash for 32 or 64 states

Comment: @VaughnCato:Can this idea work as i can store hashes as 64 bit numbers i will need 2^29 memory

Comment: @user Does transition depend only on number of true states or also on positions of true states? If it depends only on number, than there are only 36 states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the grid is a 35-bit number, so you can store the grid as an integer (on a 64-bit machine) or 2 words on a lesser one. you can keep states you've already seen in a giant direct-address array or a hash table.

Comment: :I am aware of that,but the trouble is what would be the time complexity of your solution?

Comment: lookup is constant time in an array or hash table

Comment: :is it faster than log n? and there are 2^35 states for the game ,you can't hash table with those many values that is 10^10 memory

Comment: :can you answer in more detail with a proper example ,it will really help me

Comment: remembering if you've seen 2^35 states only requires a 4GB array. and a hash table can handle smaller periods with much less memory. you can do that in RAM, a memory-mapped file, swap file, etc.

Comment: You don't need to store all possible values to detect a cycle, just the values which are part of the cycle. Yes, that means you can't detect cycles of length 2^32 that way if you're restricted to 4GB.

Comment: each bit in the 4GB array represents whether the n'th possible state was seen. all states are represented.

Comment: actually i am restricted to 64 mb of memory.

Comment: 64MB can represent 2^29 states at most. you could run out of memory before detecting a cycle, but you can always try it. you can also memory map (`mmap`) a file on disk to get more memory and use that as your lookup table.

Comment: well this a algorithm game application,I am not allowed access to external file system ,I can use memory only within the program itself

Comment: Isn't there any hashing function that could solve my problem?

Comment: As I need to store a string of zeroes and ones? Something that makes use of distance between 2 states ,some sort of encoder/decoder/mux principle?

Comment: the hash function for an integer can simply be the integer itself. the index in the hash table would be capacity % i